# Not able to get value from async storage It shows 'name' value to 'loading', However same code work in class components name 'value' change

Tags: react-native, use-state, asyncstorage

After using the setItem method value of 'name' variable should change to value entered in the textInput but console.log(item) shows 'loading' After clicking submit button at first time. Which is initial value of the 'name' variable in useState.

Once I entered the submit button again the  name variable value change to value entered in textInput.

Expected: When I click submit button at first time, item.name variable should change to textInput value

Using same code in class component work fine.

```
export default function App() {
  const arr =[] 
 const [text, setText] = useState()
  const[item,setItem] = useState([
    {name: 'loading'}
  ])
  const storedata= async ()=> {
    // setItem({name: text})
    arr.push({name: text})
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('mykey',JSON.stringify(arr));
      console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('mykey'))
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    try{
     
        setItem({item: JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('mykey'))})
       
        console.log('printing item',item)
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  

  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)}
      placeholder='type'
    />
    <Button title='change'
     onPress={storedata}
    />
      
      
  
    </View>
  );
}
```

Output:
Button click first time: printing item [{"name":"loading"}]

### Button click second time: printing item {"item":[{"name":"hi"}]}

```
class App extends React.Component{
  arr=[]
  id=0
  state= {
    text: '',
    item:[
      {name: 'loading'}
    ]
  }

  storedata = async () => {
    this.arr.push({ name: this.state.text})
   
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('mylist',JSON.stringify(this.arr));
 
    this.setState({
      item: JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('mylist'))
    })
    console.log(item)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The setState function is an asynchronous function. setState calls are batched to improve the performance of the application. So the results are not reflected immediately. That's why, you are getting the previous value for the item variable.

You can find more info [here.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-setstate-method-async/#:%7E:text=setState()%20async%20Issue%3A%20If,remember%20that%20setState%20is%20asynchronous.)

Comment: setState is giving me correct result, but setItem(declared in useSate) is giving correct value after button is clicked twice. I want to know about it. Please let me know, still you did not get the question. Thanks for your reply.